# How can I tell Jekyll not to generate pages that match some kind of pattern?

Tags: jekyll, blogs, liquid

I have a Jekyll website but some posts are still being worked on so I did not want them being rendered until they're ready.

I've managed to alter the pages that generate indexes and pagination so that these don't get included - I've changed the iterator in a liquid template so that it only includes posts that don't include a tag called `"invisible"`:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  {% unless post.tags contains "invisible" %}
  // include post in paginator
```

But I don't really know how I can achieve a similar effect with regards to the actual post pages rather than entries in the paginator.

In short, what I want to do is to **selectively stop some posts from being rendered as html based on some attribute like the presence of some tag**.

I know that one approach for this is to place these under `_drafts` rather than `_posts` but I did not want to go down that route if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this in your posts front matter `published: false`. Your post will no longer be in the `site.posts` collection.

Comment: That's an answer, thanks. I can now try to hack my local jekyll copy into looking for my special tag rather than `published: false`. Should not be hard.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida There is also the option to use drafts - see [Working with Drafts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/drafts/)